# What score should i put in boost field of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my doc, I have a field called Tag and SuperTag. Whenever a Tag matches it will boost some score, but if a match on SuperTag it will boost significantly to make it 1st choice. In your opinion, what value should I put in boost field for Tag and SuperTag? Thanks.

Comment: Are Tag and SuperTag arrays or strings?

Comment: a string but will be tokenize on index.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite difficult to be answered, It depends so much in the data that both field contains and the analyzers that they have.

Obviously if the data is going to be pretty much the same for both I would set a boost in supertag field to `2.0`.

In case they don't hold the same data we can imagine scenarios like this:

```
{tag: 'tagnice tagnice tagnice'}

{supertag: 'tagnice'}
```

even with the boosted supertag, tag could be more relevant just because `tf-idf` gives it bigger score.

To solve that for example, an analyzer setted to both with filter unique will help.

So as said, it depends so much in the data and how you store it in lucene. At first sight, without knowing that much, doubling the boost would work.